# Accessing spring context in testng's @BeforeTest

Tags: java, testng, spring-test

I would like to register some web scopes to the spring context in my `@BeforeTest` method. But it turns out that spring context is still `null` at that point.

The test runs fine though, if I change into `@BeforeMethod`. I wonder how I can access the context in `@BeforeTest`, because I don't want the scope registration code to be repeated for each test methods.

Below are my code snippets.

```
public class MyTest extends MyBaseTest {
    @Test public void someTest() { /*...*/ }
}

@ContextConfiguration(locations="/my-context.xml")
public class MyBaseTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    @BeforeTest public void registerWebScopes() {
        ConfigurableBeanFactory factory = (ConfigurableBeanFactory)
                this.applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        factory.registerScope("session", new SessionScope());
        factory.registerScope("request", new RequestScope());
    }   

    /* some protected methods here */
}
```

Here's the error message when running the test:

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest registerWebScopes
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at my.MyBaseTest.registerWebScopes(MyBaseTest.java:22)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Call `springTestContextPrepareTestInstance()` in your BeforeTest method.

Comment: Are you aware of any documentation on why injected members aren't available in `@BeforeTest` and even `@BeforeSuite` methods?

Comment: 10x :) it is easier then write bean post processor

Answer (score 5):

TestNG runs `@BeforeTest` methods before `@BeforeClass` methods. The `springTestContextPrepareTestInstance()` is annotated with `@BeforeClass` and sets up the  `applicationContext`. This is why the `applicationContext` is still `null` in a `@BeforeTest` method. `@BeforeTest` is for wapping a tagged group of tests. (It does not run before each `@Test` method, so it's a bit of a misnomer).

Instead of using `@BeforeTest`, you should probably use `@BeforeClass` (which is run once, before the first `@Test` in the current class). Be sure it depends on `springTestContextPrepareTestInstance` method, as in

```java
@BeforeClass(dependsOnMethods = "springTestContextPrepareTestInstance")
public void registerWebScopes() {
    ConfigurableBeanFactory factory = (ConfigurableBeanFactory) 
            this.applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    factory.registerScope("session", new SessionScope());
    factory.registerScope("request", new RequestScope());
}
```

The `@BeforeMethod` works, too (as you mentioned) because they run after `@BeforeClass` methods.

Comment: "`@BeforeClass` (run before any `@Tests` in the current class)". <-- This is incorrect. As stated in [TestNG documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html), `@BeforeClass` will be run before the **first** test method in the current class is invoked.

Comment: @JonyD, thanks for pointing this out, the wording is not clear. I've edited it based on your suggestion.